# What is the difference between "Select Active Profiles" and "Run Configuration: profiles" in Eclipse with m2e?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2eclipse, m2e

Currently I have a Maven project in Eclipse Luna.

I defined a profile in the pom.xml:

```
    <profile>
        <id>prof</id>
        <properties>
            <deploy.local.backupDir>/cygdrive/c/Users/Ferrarim/Sandbox/FSD/backup</deploy.local.backupDir>
            <deploy.local.warDir>/cygdrive/c/Users/Ferrarim/Workspaces/eclipse-luna-fsd/fsd-backend/target</deploy.local.warDir>
        </properties>
    </profile>
```

I can find it under (right click on the project in Eclipse): Maven->Select Active profiles.

I can also create a Maven Run Configuration and put "prof" in the profiles option of the Run Configuration, but it's ignored during the build.

Can someone please explain the difference between the two approaches?

I would like to the second approach (select profiles via Run Configuration)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to disable "Build Automatically" under Project menu in Eclipse. Obvious after thinking about it...

Edit (to clarify): "Select Maven profiles" is used to choose which profiles are needed during the automatic Eclipse build.